# Why is the hr on same line as div element even after applying hr after closing div tag

Tags: html, css, css-float

i have two div elements that float on both sides (Left And Right). i applied hr tag after closing the first div tag (That floats left) and before opening the next div tag (That floats right). But the hr tag is displayed at the top background. To see the hr tag, see the small connecting line between the two divs (At the top).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.leftmovie {
        border: solid;
        float: left;
        width: 47%;
        margin-left: 2em;
        height: 400px;
    }
    .rightmovie {
        border:solid;
        float: right;
        width: 47%;
        margin-right:2em;
        height:400px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Row">
        <div class="leftmovie">
            <span class="Star">ergjkh<br>kdjnkj</span>
        </div>
        <div class="rightmovie">legnlejgn<br>gegerge</div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="leftmovie">
            <span class="Star">ergjkh<br>kdjnkj</span>
        </div>
        <div class="rightmovie">legnlejgn<br>gegerge</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try a clear: both on the hr to make sure you have, well, cleared from the floated divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't use `clear: both` after applying `float` property.

Add this in `hr` tag.

```html
hr {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```